# Как правильно организовать проверку категорий?

Tags: url, php, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте! Решил создать категории с бесконечной вложенностью. Конечно на практике не будет превышать 5.

Есть база

С колонками: **id,name,url,parent**.

И url **http://site.ru/catalog/category/category/category**

Как правильно определить текущею категорию, проверив все родительские на существование?
Может есть готовые решения для codeigniter?

Все было бы просто если в url были их id.  Как сделать тут?

Нужно достать id категорий, проверить цепочку на правильность и что бы в итоге не создавать сильную нагрузку на бд.

Comment: А для чего это вам??? Т.е смысл проверять?

Comment: @navi1893, вдруг попадется 2 дочерние категории с одинаковым url?

К примеру http://localhost/computer/other и http://localhost/tv/other.
Это же будут совсем 2 разные категории.

Или есть какой то другой алгоритм?

Comment: > Как правильно определить текущею категорию, проверив все родительские на существование?

Идя циклом вверх (или вниз) по одной и выдавая 404 на несоответствии. Других вариантов нет, насколько знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Идя циклом вверх (или вниз) по одной и выдавая 404 на несоответствии.